# Не могу понять почему выдаёт ошибку "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python

пытаюсь перепройти некоторые уровни Python Challenge. во втором задании нужно переставить в тексте буквы по алфавиту.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as low
file=open("pch0.txt","r").read()

low=list(low)

result = ""
for i in file:
        if i == low[24] or i == low[25]:
        result += low[int(low.index(i)-24)]
if i in low:
    result += low[int(low.index(i))+2]
else:
    result += i
```

в итоге получается "i hope you didnt tra"
всё вроде идёт нормально до 20ого символа. И вот уже второй день не могу понять почему.

P.S. в файле "pch0.txt" текст

> "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp.
>   bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm
>   jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас идет превышение количества символов в массиве попробуйте вот так

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as low

file = open("pch0.txt", "r").read()

low = list(low)

result = ""
for i in file:
    if i == low[24] or i == low[25]:
        result += low[int(low.index(i) - 24)]

    if i in low:
       if int(low.index(i) + 2) < 25:
            result += low[int(low.index(i) + 2)]
    else:
        result += i
print(result) # i hope you didnt translate it by hand. thats what computers are for. doing it in by hand is inefficient and that's why this text is so long. using string.maketrans() is recommended. now apply on the url.
```